# php get youtube video id not working

Tags: php, if-statement, youtube

I am using the following code to get the ID of a youtube video from a user inputted form:

```
$ma_video_link_url = $ma_video_link_url;
parse_str( parse_url( $ma_video_link_url, PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
$ma_video_id = $v;
```

From here I have the following php code to output it as HTML:

```
if ( $ma_video_on_click == 'ma_video_lightbox' ) {
     $ma_video_link_start = '<a href="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ma_video_id.'">'; 
     $ma_video_link_content = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$ma_video_id.'/0.jpg">';
     $ma_video_link_end = '</a>';
} else {
    $ma_video_link_start = '';
    $ma_video_link_content = '<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ma_video_id.'?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $ma_video_link_end = '';
}

$output .= '<article class="skizzar_masonry_entry '.$vid_double_width_class.' '.$el_class.'">';
$output .= $ma_video_link_start;
$output .= $ma_video_link_content;    
$output .= $ma_video_link_end;
$output .= '</article>';
return $output;
```

I am noticing some odd behaviour though within the if statement, in the first instance (i.e. `if ( $ma_video_on_click == 'ma_video_lightbox' ) {`) everything works fine and the video ID is taken from the URL the user inputs and added to the html code. However, in the `else` statement, the `$ma_video_id` variable doesn't work at all.

Is there any reason this is happening and can someone help me fix the issue.

All that is being outputted in the html on my site is the following:

```
<article class="skizzar_masonry_entry " style="position: absolute; left: 855px; top: 428px;">

<iframe width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0"></iframe>

</article>
```

Full php source code as follows:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Skizzar | Masonry Anything
Description: Adds a masonry gallery of any items to visual composer
Author: Skizzar
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.skizzar.com
*/
// Init Masonry
if ( ! function_exists( 'slug_masonry_init' )) :
wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'masonry-anything-css', 'http://samskirrow.skizzar.netdna-cdn.com/css/jquery.fancybox.css', array() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry-anything-js', 'http://samskirrow.skizzar.netdna-cdn.com/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.3.3', true );
function slug_masonry_init() { ?>
<style>
#skizzar_masonry_loop {
margin:0px auto;
}
.skizzar_masonry_entry img {
display:block;
}
.skizzar_ma_textbox {
padding:20px;
}
.clickable img:hover {
opacity:0.6;
transform: scale(1.1);
}
.skizzar_ma_overlay {
width:auto;
position:absolute;
color:white;
font-size:3.25rem;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
left:50%;
top:120%;
text-align:center;
z-index:1;
transition:none !important;
pointer-events:none;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {  
$(".skizzar_ma_fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        }
    }
});  
$(".skizzar_masonry_entry").hover(function(){
$('.skizzar_ma_overlay', this).stop().animate({'top': '50%'}, 400);
}, function(){
$('.skizzar_ma_overlay', this).stop().animate({'top': '120%'}, 400);
}); 
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

});
</script>
<?php }
//add to wp_footer
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'slug_masonry_init' );
endif; // ! slug_masonry_init exists

if(!class_exists('Skizzar_Masonry')) 
{
class Skizzar_Masonry
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('admin_init',array($this,'skizzar_masonry_init'));
            add_shortcode('skizzar_masonry',array($this,'skizzar_masonry_shortcode'));
            add_shortcode('skizzar_masonry_image',array($this,'skizzar_masonry_image_shortcode'));
            add_shortcode('skizzar_masonry_video',array($this,'skizzar_masonry_video_shortcode'));
            add_shortcode('skizzar_masonry_text',array($this,'skizzar_masonry_text_shortcode'));

    }
    function skizzar_masonry_init()
    {
        if(function_exists('vc_map'))
        {
            vc_map(
                array(
                    "name" => __("Masonry Anything"),
                    "base" => "skizzar_masonry",
                    "class" => "skizzar_masonry",
                    "icon" => "skizzar_masonry",
                    "category" => __("Skizzar","skizzar"),
                    "description" => __("Add various media items in a masonry grid","skizzar"),
                    "as_parent" => array('skizzar_masonry_image', 'skizzar_masonry_video', 'skizzar_masonry_text'), 
                    "content_element" => true,
                    "show_settings_on_create" => true,
                    "js_view" => 'VcColumnView',
                    "params" => array(                          
                        // Play with icon selector
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Item Width", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "masonry_item_width",
                            "value" => 240,
                            "suffix" => "px",
                            "description" => __("Specify the width of each item in the masonry gallery", "skizzar"),
                        ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Item Padding", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "masonry_item_padding",
                            "value" => 5,
                            "suffix" => "px",
                            "description" => __("Padding between each masonry item", "skizzar"),

                        ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Extra Class","skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "el_class",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Write your own CSS and mention the class name here.", "flip-box"),
                        ),
                    )
                )
            );
            vc_map(
                array(
                   "name" => __("Masonry Image"),
                   "base" => "skizzar_masonry_image",
                   "class" => "skizzar_masonry_image",
                   "icon" => "skizzar_masonry_image", //to do
                   "category" => __("Skizzar","skizzar"),
                   "description" => __("Masonry item image","skizzar"),
                   "as_child" => array('only' => 'skizzar_masonry'), 
                   "show_settings_on_create" => true,
                   "params" => array(
                        // Play with icon selector
                        array(
                            "type" => "attach_image",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Upload Image", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "skizzar_masonry_img",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Upload your image", "skizzar"),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Action on click', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_image_on_click",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Do nothing', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_image_nowt',
                                    __( 'Open Lightbox Image', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_image_lightbox',
                                    __( 'Custom Link', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_image_custom_link',
                            ),
                            'description' => __( 'What to do when you click on an image', 'skizzar' ),
                        ),
                       array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "heading" => __("Custom Link", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "ma_image_custom_link_url",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Enter the link for your image", "skizzar"),
                            "dependency" => array(
                               "element" => "ma_image_on_click",
                               "value" => "ma_image_custom_link",
                           ),

                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Custom Link Target', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_image_custom_link_target",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Same Window', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_image_same_window',
                                    __( 'New Window', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_image_new_window',
                            ),
                            'description' => __( 'Select where to open custom links', 'skizzar' ),
                            "dependency" => array(
                               "element" => "ma_image_on_click",
                               "value" => "ma_image_custom_link",
                           ),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "checkbox",
                           "holder" => "",
                           "class" => "",
                           "heading" => __("Double item width", 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_image_double",
                           "value" => array(__("Yes", "skizzar") => 'on'),
                           "description" => __("Make this item double width", 'skizzar')
                       ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Custom CSS Class", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "el_class",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Ran out of options? Need more styles? Write your own CSS and mention the class name here.", "skizzar"),

                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
            vc_map(
                array(
                   "name" => __("Masonry Video"),
                   "base" => "skizzar_masonry_video",
                   "class" => "skizzar_masonry_video",
                   "icon" => "skizzar_masonry_video", //to do
                   "category" => __("Skizzar","skizzar"),
                   "description" => __("Masonry item video","skizzar"),
                   "as_child" => array('only' => 'skizzar_masonry'), 
                   "show_settings_on_create" => true,
                   "params" => array(
                        // Play with icon selector
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "heading" => __("Youtube video url", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "ma_video_link_url",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Enter the youtube video address)", "skizzar"),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Action on click', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_video_on_click",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Do nothing', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_video_nowt',
                                    __( 'Open Lightbox Image', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_video_lightbox',
                            ),
                            'description' => __( 'What to do when you click on the video', 'skizzar' ),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "checkbox",
                           "holder" => "",
                           "class" => "",
                           "heading" => __("Double item width", 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_video_double",
                           "value" => array(__("Yes", "skizzar") => 'on'),
                           "description" => __("Make this item double width", 'skizzar')
                       ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Custom CSS Class", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "el_class",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Ran out of options? Need more styles? Write your own CSS and mention the class name here.", "skizzar"),

                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
            vc_map(
                array(
                   "name" => __("Masonry Text Block"),
                   "base" => "skizzar_masonry_text",
                   "class" => "skizzar_masonry_text",
                   "icon" => "skizzar_masonry_text", //to do
                   "category" => __("Skizzar","skizzar"),
                   "description" => __("Masonry item text","skizzar"),
                   "as_child" => array('only' => 'skizzar_masonry'), 
                   "show_settings_on_create" => true,
                   "params" => array(
                        // Play with icon selector
                        array(
                            "type" => "textarea_html",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Your text", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "ma_skizzar_text",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Your text goes here", "skizzar"),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "colorpicker",
                           "heading" => __( 'Text area background color', 'skizzar' ),
                           "param_name" => "ma_skizzar_text_bg",
                           "value" => '#c3cbc8',
                       ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "colorpicker",
                           "heading" => __( 'Text color', 'skizzar' ),
                           "param_name" => "ma_skizzar_text_color",
                           "value" => '#333333',
                       ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Text Align', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_skizzar_text_align",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Left', 'skizzar' ) => 'left',
                                    __( 'Center', 'skizzar' ) => 'center',
                                    __( 'Right', 'skizzar' ) => 'right',

                           ),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Action on click', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_text_on_click",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Do nothing', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_text_nowt',
                                    __( 'Custom Link', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_text_custom_link',
                            ),
                            'description' => __( 'What to do when you click on your text', 'skizzar' ),
                        ),
                       array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "heading" => __("Custom Link", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "ma_text_custom_link_url",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Enter the link for your text", "skizzar"),
                            "dependency" => array(
                               "element" => "ma_text_on_click",
                               "value" => "ma_text_custom_link",
                           ),

                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "dropdown",
                           "heading" => __( 'Custom Link Target', 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_text_custom_link_target",
                           "value" => array(
                                    __( 'Same Window', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_text_same_window',
                                    __( 'New Window', 'skizzar' ) => 'ma_text_new_window',
                            ),
                            'description' => __( 'Select where to open custom links', 'skizzar' ),
                            "dependency" => array(
                               "element" => "ma_text_on_click",
                               "value" => "ma_text_custom_link",
                           ),
                        ),
                       array(
                           "type" => "checkbox",
                           "holder" => "",
                           "class" => "",
                           "heading" => __("Double item width", 'skizzar'),
                           "param_name" => "ma_text_double",
                           "value" => array(__("Yes", "skizzar") => 'on'),
                           "description" => __("Make this item double width", 'skizzar')
                       ),
                        array(
                            "type" => "textfield",
                            "class" => "",
                            "heading" => __("Custom CSS Class", "skizzar"),
                            "param_name" => "el_class",
                            "value" => "",
                            "description" => __("Ran out of options? Need more styles? Write your own CSS and mention the class name here.", "skizzar"),

                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
        }
    }
    // Shortcode handler function for list Icon
    function skizzar_masonry_shortcode($atts,$content = null)
    {
        global $skizzar_masonry_item_width, $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;
        $el_class = '';
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            "masonry_item_width" => '',
            "masonry_item_padding" => '',
            "el_class" => '',
        ),$atts));



        $skizzar_masonry_item_width = $masonry_item_width;
        $skizzar_masonry_item_padding = $masonry_item_padding;

        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($) {  
var container = document.querySelector("#skizzar_masonry_loop");
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: '.$masonry_item_width.',
  gutter: '.$masonry_item_padding.',
  itemSelector: ".skizzar_masonry_entry"
});</script>';
        $output .= '<style>.skizzar_masonry_entry, .skizzar_masonry_entry img {width:'.$masonry_item_width.'px;} .skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double, .skizzar_masonry_entry.skizzar_ma_double img {width:560px; /* + padding */} .skizzar_masonry_entry {margin-bottom:'.$masonry_item_padding.'px; overflow:hidden;}</style>';
        $output .= '<div id="skizzar_masonry_loop" class="'.$el_class.'">';
        $output .= do_shortcode($content);
        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;
    }
    // Masonry Img
    function skizzar_masonry_image_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

        $skizzar_masonry_image = $ma_image_on_click = $ma_image_double = $masonry_item_width = $el_class = $masonry_item_padding = '';

        extract($a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'skizzar_masonry_img' => '',                        
            'ma_image_on_click' => 'ma_image_nowt',
            'ma_image_custom_link_url' => '',
            'ma_image_custom_link_target' => '',
            'ma_image_double' => '0',
            'el_class'=>'',
        ),$atts));

        global $skizzar_masonry_item_width, $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;
        if(empty($masonry_item_width))
            $masonry_item_width = $skizzar_masonry_item_width;

        if(empty($masonry_item_padding))
            $masonry_item_padding = $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;

        $bloginfo = get_bloginfo('name');
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($a["skizzar_masonry_img"], "large");
        $imgSrc = $img[0];

        if ($ma_image_custom_link_target == 'ma_image_new_window') {
            $ma_image_custom_link_target = '_blank';
        } else {
            $ma_image_custom_link_target = '';
        }

        if ( $ma_image_on_click == 'ma_image_lightbox' ) {
            $ma_image_link_start = '<i class="skizzar_ma_overlay fa fa-search"></i><a class="skizzar_ma_fancybox clickable" href="'.$imgSrc.'">';
            $ma_image_link_end = '</a>';
        } else if ( $ma_image_on_click == 'ma_image_custom_link' ) {
            $ma_image_link_start = '<i class="skizzar_ma_overlay fa fa-globe"></i><a class="clickable" href="' . $ma_image_custom_link_url . '" target="'.$ma_image_custom_link_target.'">';
            $ma_image_link_end = '</a>';
        }
        else {
            $ma_image_link_start = '';
            $ma_image_link_end = '';
        }
        if ($ma_image_double == 'on') {
            $double_width_class = 'skizzar_ma_double';
        } else {
            $double_width_class = '';
        }   

            $output .= '<article class="skizzar_masonry_entry '.$double_width_class.' '.$el_class.'">';
            $output .= $ma_image_link_start;
            $output .= '<img src="'.$imgSrc.'" alt="'.$bloginfo.'" />';    
            $output .= $ma_image_link_end;
            $output .= '</article>';
        return $output;
    }
    // Masonry Vid
    function skizzar_masonry_video_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

        $skizzar_masonry_video = $ma_video_double = $ma_video_link_url = $ma_video_on_click = $masonry_item_width = $el_class = $masonry_item_padding = '';

        extract($a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'ma_video_link_url' => '',                      
            'ma_video_on_click' => 'ma_video_nowt',
            'ma_video_double' => '0',
            'el_class'=>'',
        ),$atts));


        global $skizzar_masonry_item_width, $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;
        if(empty($masonry_item_width))
            $masonry_item_width = $skizzar_masonry_item_width;

        if(empty($masonry_item_padding))
            $masonry_item_padding = $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;

        $bloginfo = get_bloginfo('name');

        $ma_video_link_url = $ma_video_link_url;
        parse_str( parse_url( $ma_video_link_url, PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
        $ma_video_id = $v;

        if ( $ma_video_on_click == 'ma_video_lightbox' ) {
            $ma_video_link_start = '<i class="skizzar_ma_overlay fa fa-camera"></i><a class="skizzar_ma_fancybox clickable fancybox.iframe"  href="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ma_video_id.'">'; 
            $ma_video_link_content = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$ma_video_id.'/0.jpg" alt="'.$bloginfo.'">';
            $ma_video_link_end = '</a>';
        } 
        else {
            $ma_video_link_start = '';
            $ma_video_link_content = '<iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$ma_video_id.'?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            $ma_video_link_end = '';
        }
        if ($ma_video_double == 'on') {
            $vid_double_width_class = 'skizzar_ma_double';
        } else {
            $vid_double_video_class = '';
        }  

            $output .= '<article class="skizzar_masonry_entry '.$vid_double_width_class.' '.$el_class.'">';
            $output .= $ma_video_link_start;
            $output .= $ma_video_link_content;    
            $output .= $ma_video_link_end;
            $output .= '</article>';
        return $output;
    }
    // Masonry text
    function skizzar_masonry_text_shortcode($atts, $content = null){

        $skizzar_masonry_text = $ma_skizzar_text_bg = $ma_skizzar_text_color = $ma_skizzar_text_align = $ma_text_double = $ma_text_on_click = $masonry_item_width = $el_class = $masonry_item_padding = '';

        extract($a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'ma_skizzar_text'  => '',
            'ma_skizzar_text_bg' => '',
            'ma_skizzar_text_color' => '',
            'ma_skizzar_text_align' => '',
            'ma_text_on_click' => 'ma_text_nowt',
            'ma_text_custom_link_url' => '',
            'ma_text_custom_link_target' => '',
            'ma_text_double' => '0',
            'el_class'=>'',
        ),$atts));

        global $skizzar_masonry_item_width, $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;
        if(empty($masonry_item_width))
            $masonry_item_width = $skizzar_masonry_item_width;

        if(empty($masonry_item_padding))
            $masonry_item_padding = $skizzar_masonry_item_padding;

        $bloginfo = get_bloginfo('name');

        if ($ma_text_custom_link_target == 'ma_text_new_window') {
            $ma_text_custom_link_target = '_blank';
        } else {
            $ma_text_custom_link_target = '';
        }

        if ( $ma_text_on_click == 'ma_text_custom_link' ) {
            $ma_text_link_start = '<a href="' . $ma_text_custom_link_url . '" target="'.$ma_text_custom_link_target.'">';
            $ma_text_link_end = '</a>';
        }
        else {
            $ma_text_link_start = '';
            $ma_text_link_end = '';
        }

        if ($ma_text_double == 'on') {
            $text_double_width_class = 'skizzar_ma_double';
        } else {
            $text_double_width_class = '';
        }  

            $output .= '<style>.skizzar_ma_textbox p, .skizzar_ma_textbox h1, .skizzar_ma_textbox h2, .skizzar_ma_textbox h3, .skizzar_ma_textbox h4, .skizzar_ma_textbox h5, .skizzar_ma_textbox h6, .skizzar_ma_textbox a, .skizzar_ma_textbox em {color:'.$ma_skizzar_text_color.' !important;}</style>';
            $output .= '<article class="clickable skizzar_masonry_entry skizzar_ma_textbox '.$text_double_width_class.' '.$el_class.'" style="background:'.$ma_skizzar_text_bg.'; text-align:'.$ma_skizzar_text_align.'">';
            $output .= $ma_text_link_start;
            $output .= $ma_skizzar_text;    
            $output .= $ma_text_link_end;
            $output .= '</article>';
        return $output;
    }
}
} 

if(class_exists('Skizzar_Masonry'))
{
$Skizzar_Masonry = new Skizzar_Masonry;
}
//Extend WPBakeryShortCodesContainer class to inherit all required     functionality
if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
class WPBakeryShortCode_skizzar_masonry extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {
}
}
if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCode' ) ) {
class WPBakeryShortCode_skizzar_masonry_image extends WPBakeryShortCode {
}
class WPBakeryShortCode_skizzar_masonry_video extends WPBakeryShortCode {
}
class WPBakeryShortCode_skizzar_masonry_text extends WPBakeryShortCode {
}

}
```

Comment: where exactly is `$ma_video_id` variable assigned? or in `$ma_video_id = $v;` where does $v come from?

Comment: $v is in a youtube video url, for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Xt0B0f9dms

Comment: can you include the full source?

Comment: @OzgurBar just added it

Comment: `$ma_video_id = $v;` ok, can't see `$v` getting assigned in the code. is it specified in querystring or something like that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, I used the code from a tutorial I found - just interesting that it works for the videos in one statement but not another. I guess the solution is to find another way to get the video ID from the url